# Is there any standard for the level or depth of JSON?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I usually make deep level JSON, but not sure if this is a good code.

I wrote down my code below.
I usually do this when I need to return value to client.

```py
def nested_dict():
    return defaultdict(nested_dict)

result = defaultdict(nested_dict)
result["a"]["b"]["c"]["d"] = value
```

This comes in handy to make a dict(or JSON) that will be sent to client.

There is no harm to do this and works fine with `json.dumps` or `flask.jsonify`.

But it seems not really good to have a deep level of depth in JSON.

Is there any solution or recommended standard?

Comment: Some JSON encoders have depth limits to avoid endless recursion. But those limits are somewhere in the *hundreds*. You'd have to try pretty hard to reach that level of depth manually. If it makes sense for your data structure to have 5 levels of depth, that's fine…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. Also, one can not even say that 4 *looks* too many in general: if they were three coordinates and some properties of the pointed position at the end (sparse data in 3D), you would not bat an eye.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no defined limit; and there really couldn't be.